# Decimal float to int conversion error in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following code in python,

```
x = 0.29
x = int(x*100)
print(x)
```

It prints 28, and this is causing an infinite loop in my code.
How do I resolve this issue? I think this is some machine precision issue.
I my program I want the value of int(x*100) to be 29.

Comment: `0.29` is already inaccurate as a `float` You should use `double` to get more accurace, but the problem may remain. This is inherent in floating-point.

Comment: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/674039)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're encountering a floating-point precision issue, try using the `Decimal` library which is designed to give better precision with floating-point numbers:

```
from decimal import Decimal

x = Decimal('0.29')
x = int(x * 100)
print(x)
```

Should output `29` as you expect.

---

As per OP comment:

```
from decimal import Decimal

def get_float():
    return 0.29  # Simulating the function that returns a float

x = int(Decimal(str(get_float())) * 100)
print(x)
```

Comment: I am getting it as a float from another function, is it possible to convert it to decimal so that I can retain the value 29?

Comment: Yes, convert to string first. See update.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common decimal computing problem in Python.
You can use following code to accomplish your goal:

```
from decimal import *
x = Decimal('0.29')
print(x * 100)
```

Ref: [Python Decimal Module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html)

Answer (score 0):

The application of the above code or remaining part of the code is unknown. So for the above issue based on the known circumstances, this is one of the solutions:

```
x = 0.29
x = round(x*100,0)
x = int(x)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [math](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) which is an in-built python library.

```py
import math

x = 0.29
x = x*100
print(math.ceil(x)) # prints 29
```